# How do I load a field collection from a node?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a node that has a few field collections on it.

When I look at `node_load()` output, I see:

```
[field_rich_text_group] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 7
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 8
                        )

                )

        )
```

What API function can I use to actually load the field data contained in the collection that has an entity_id of 6, 7, 8, etc?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Doh! I should have looked in the field collection module:

```
entity_load('field_collection_item', array($item_id))
```

Comment: I am looking for similar solution. How do you write the output and placed them into rendered array? Thanks

Comment: I wrote a bunch of custom functions to build the layout for these items. Sadly they return HTML, not renderable arrays. It would be nice to use renderable arrays, but I'm not completely clear on the point (I'm sure there is a good reason to do it, I just haven't found an explanation that resonates).

Comment: Thanks. Field colection is indeed useful to ease up forms, and output, but when it comes to custom queries, I seem to have to dive into the nested arrays, even using entity_metadata_wrapper.

Comment: Oh yah, I wrote wrappers that just turn the dense arrays into the what I need.

Comment: entity_load() returns a set of nodes which are specific to "entity" and along with them we get the user defined fields too. How do we differentiate the user fields from the fields of an entity? Any clues?

Answer (score 41):

There is also a wrapper function that does the same trick:

[`field_collection_item_load($id, $reset = FALSE)`](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/misc/field_collection--field_collection.module/function/field_collection_item_load/7.x)

or as per comment, use:

```
field_collection_item_load_multiple($ids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE)
```

to load multiple collections (for example if you have an *Add more* buttons).

Comment: As per @vasiliy-grotov 's answer above you can also use `field_collection_item_load_multiple($ids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE)`, to load multiple collections (for example if you have an "Add more" btn).

Answer (score 22):

[field_collection_field_get_entity()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!field_collection!field_collection.module/function/field_collection_field_get_entity/7) should be used in order to load the correct revision.

Example usage:

```
$node = node_load(1);
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_fc');
foreach ($items as $item) {
 $fc = field_collection_field_get_entity($item);
 // Do something.
}
```

Comment: how to get the date fields assigned in the field collection? I used the following thing.$item = field_collection_field_get_entity($itemid);print $item->field_course_starts_on['und'][0]['safe_value']; .But no values are printing for it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was getting constant Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! with ...item_load() and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `entity_metadata_wrapper` from the [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module:

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$field_collection = $node_wrapper->field_rich_text_group[0]->value();
dpm($field_collection);
```

You can loop all the collections as well:

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
foreach ($node_wrapper->field_rich_text_group as $field_collection_wrapper) {
  $field_collection = $field_collection_wrapper->value();
  dpm($field_collection);
}
```