# delete a specific element within field collection programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

This is driving me crazy it just sounds simple, but I cannot find the answer.

I have a field collection in a content type called `field_collection_mine` how you now while creating the node you can add elements to the field collection.

I have tried this:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
$wrapper->field_collection_mine = array();
entity_save('field_collection_item',$wrapper);
```

The code above delete all the elements within the field collection, but that is now what I want!! I just want to delete for example the last element. E.g:

- Field Collection mine
- Element1
- Element2
- Element3

How can I for example delete just the element 3? The above code deletes all the elements, so `field_collection_mine` is left empty.

Comment: Check @milkovsky answer here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/how-do-i-load-a-field-collection-from-a-node

I think it is what you want

Comment: I already can access to the items of the field collection! this one for access to the first item $wrapper_egresos->field_salida_mercanc_a[0] but when I try to delete the item with unset, then in the node I cannot see the items but if I do a dpm to the array of items I can still see the other items, but they are not displayed. help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could achieve what I wanted. What I did was this:

In my case I wanted to delete the last item within the field collection.

Take a look to this code, for beginners: **remember that you must have the `$entity` already loaded**, e.g.

```
// Remove the field value
unset($entity->field_salida_mercanc_a[LANGUAGE_NONE][count($entity->field_salida_mercanc_a[LANGUAGE_NONE])-1]);

// Reset the array to zero-based sequential keys
$entity->field_salida_mercanc_a[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array_values($entity->field_salida_mercanc_a[LANGUAGE_NONE]);

// Save the entity
entity_save($entity_type, $entity);
```

Thats all! The other way is:

```
// Get the node wapper
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
// Get the last position of the array items, thanks to the ->value() statement you can get the complete Array properties.
$field_collection_item_value = $wrapper->field_collection_mine[count($wrapper->field_collection_mine->value())-1]->value();
// Do not use 'unset' to delete the item due to is not the correct way, I use the entity_delete_multiple provided by the entity API
entity_delete_multiple('field_collection_item', array($field_collection_item_value->item_id));
```

The way above is good using `entity_metadata_wrapper` function, but with that way there is a complex bug that I do not know how to solve it, you can check it at [#1880312](https://drupal.org/node/1880312) and after apply [the patch in #9](https://drupal.org/node/2186689) you get the next issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the id of the field collection and wrap itself in an entity wrapper. Use the save method in the wrapper to do this instead of the `entity_save` function. E.g.

```
 $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $entity);
 $wrapper->field_specific_field_collection_item->set("");
```

or:

```
$wrapper->field_specific_field_collection_item = array();
$wrapper->save();
```

Comment: Look I do not with what I should replace 'field_specific_field_collection_item' as the unic thing I have is the machine name of my field collection 'field_collection_mine'.

Comment: The field collection can contain unlimited number of items, where each item has two fields (date and quantity) how can I delete the last added item?