# Updated an empty field collection in Drupal7

Tags: entities

New to Drupal and I'm assuming the answer is simple, I've looked through the test suites etc. and still missing the point it seems.

I have a node with a field collection (field_theatre_date_set) that will store a number of dates and times. I have loaded the node and the collection is there but it's empty.

I have used various forms of this and an obvious problem is that the $field_collection_item_value below array structure just isn't there.

Any further pointers greatly received.

```
$loop=0;
foreach($showing_array as $key=>$value){

 $date='xxxx';
 $time='xxxx';

 $field_collection_item_value = $node->field_theatre_date_set[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];      
 $field_collection_item = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($field_collection_item_value)); // Load that field collection item 

 $field_collection_item->field_theatre_date_set_date[$node->language][$loop]['value'] = $date;          
 $field_collection_item->field_theatre_date_set_time[$node->language][$loop]['value'] = $time;
 $loop++
}
 $field_collection_item->save();
```

/****Update*****/

Progress has been made. I still have an empty field_collection reference that needs to store a date and time.

I now understand that field collections store a value and a revision_id. I now need to work out how to store these revisions. I have the following code:

```
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_theatre_date_set'));

$field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node);
$field_collection_item->date[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['date']   = $date;
$field_collection_item->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['time']   = $time;               
$field_collection_item->save();
```

Now when I output the field_collection_item I see the following where I am expecting to see the the value and revision:

```
[field_theatre_date_set] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [entity] => FieldCollectionItemEntity Object
 *RECURSION*
                            )

                    )

            )
```

And at the very bottom of the array I have the dates and times wallowing on their own:

```
[date] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2014-03-13
                    )

            )

    )

[time] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [time] => 19:45:00
                    )

            )

    )
```

Any pointers on how to move them into my field_theatre_date_set if they aren't expecting date and time values?

Thanks all for looking!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to load and save the node to which the field collection is attached.

This question: [Modifying a field collection programmatically missing hostEntity fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731629/modifying-a-field-collection-programmatically-missing-hostentity-fields) is slightly different but the examples are accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will take a look.

I thought by using $node->language I was doing just that, I will review the other question and report back.

Answer (score 0):

try using the [EntityAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) to load the `node` and inspect it using the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module. The EntityAPI will also make creating/editing the field collection easier.

There are lots of ways to save or load a field collection, for examples see:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1393552#comment-5428548

or any of the various answers here:
[How do I load a field collection from a node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/how-do-i-load-a-field-collection-from-a-node)