# How to count number of field collection items for a row in a view?

Tags: views, entities

I just want to count the number of field collections items in a row. I am working on a view. In the view I am able to show the field collection items value, but I do not want the value I just want to count number of items per row.

I am trying view aggregate but its showing sql errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be possible with just using Views. I find it easier to do this type of 2-step logic in Drupal with additional information.

For example use [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module to store an `integer` value in the field on `node save` for a custom computed field called `number_of_fc_values` or whatever you want to call it. You then just count the number of field collection items on save using PHP.

For example your PHP could look like the following for the computed value PHP field, this example API usage is taken from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/84282/3279

```
$node_with_fc = node_load($node->nid);
$items = field_get_items('node', $node_with_fc, 'NAME_OF_FC_FIELD');
return count($items);
```

Now in your View you simply add your `number_of_fc_values` field to the field values for the row display.