# How to theme Bean block in drupal 7

Tags: theming, blocks

I have create a custom block using [Bean](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean). It have a field collection and that field collection have 8 values. I have create a bean.tpl.php to override block. Now i need to know how can i get that field collection values using loop inside bean.tpl.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need enable for create tpl name bean.tpl.php call for every bean type.

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

In this tpl you get $content variable . Please print_r($content) in tpl or install devel module to dmp($content). I suggested you install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module. After that you can find your field collection

Load field collection like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/how-do-i-load-a-field-collection-from-a-node)

Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65282/discussion-on-answer-by-pankaj-yogi-how-to-theme-bean-block-in-drupal-7).