# Get Field Collection values not IDs

Tags: entities

I am searching for a solution for past few days but can't find it :(

I have exposed a node with rest api views and there's a couple of field collections inside my node which i want to access over API but the api is retuning field collection IDs not the actual data. How can i get the values of field collection without sending aother request to api for values?

```
"field_custom_data": {

"und": [

 {
   "value": "3",
   "revision_id": "3"
 },
 {
   "value": "4",
   "revision_id": "4"
 },
 {
   "value": "5",
   "revision_id": "5"
 },
 {
   "value": "6",
   "revision_id": "6"
 },
 {
   "value": "7",
   "revision_id": "7"
 },
 {
   "value": "8",
   "revision_id": "8"
 }
] },
```

Answer (score 0):

Before returning response to api you should load field collection using field collection ID, then you can get fields value of field collection.

```
entity_load('field_collection_item', array($item_id))
```

**Source:** [How to load field collection](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/11063/36948)

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh Kushwaha, but how do i intercept the API response to add add those values? thanks.